# Simple bar chart on d3 JS

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to this library and I don't understand why the rect bars have a negative value. I'm using d3-node (d3 v4) with jsdom to render svg from server.

This is what I tried :

```
var data = [
{
  "name" : "Nom Prénom",
  "value1" : 40,
  "value2" : 100,
  "value3" : 10,
  "total" : 150 //a changer
}
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


 var svg = this.d3n
        .createSVG(GRAPH_WIDTH - MARGINS.left - MARGINS.right - LEGEND_PANEL.width, GRAPH_HEIGHT - MARGINS.top - MARGINS.bottom)
        .append('g');


var stack = d3.stack().keys(["value1","value2","value3"]).order(d3.stackOrderNone).offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

 var dataSet = stack(data);

  //set x, y and colors

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);  

  var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


   //define and draw axis 
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(x).ticks(5).tickFormat(function(d){ return d;});

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);



 // Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
 var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d) { 
  return x(d[0]);
 })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[0] + d[1]); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]); })
.attr("width", x.bandwidth())
.on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
.on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
  var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
  var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
  tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
  tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
});
```

And the svg looks like this

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360" height="250"><g><g class="y axis" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="end"><path class="domain" stroke="#000" d="M-6,0.5H0.5V770.5H-6"></path></g><g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,445)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle"><path class="domain" stroke="#000" d="M0.5,6V0.5H770.5V6"></path></g><g class="cost" style="fill: b33040;"><rect y="-17355" height="445" width="770"></rect></g><g class="cost" style="fill: #d25c4d;"><rect y="-79655" height="-17355" width="770"></rect></g><g class="cost" style="fill: #f2b447;"><rect y="-128605" height="-61855" width="770"></rect></g></g></svg>
```

It's kinda hard to see some v4 tutorials, it seems there is a lot of changes between v3 and v4. Could you please explain in which part this is wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, looks like there are some issues with height and width:

```
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Gives us `width = 770` and `height = 445`. But

```
.createSVG(GRAPH_WIDTH - MARGINS.left - MARGINS.right - LEGEND_PANEL.width, GRAPH_HEIGHT - MARGINS.top - MARGINS.bottom)
```

ends up with `<svg width="360" height="250">`.

Then, you're getting negative `height` and `y` because of missing domain part in your `y.scaleLinear` declaration:

```
 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);
```

It should be something like:

```
 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 150])
        .range([height, 0])
```

D3 `scaleLinear()` returns function which translates every point from your data dimension (in this case it's [0, 150], where 0 and 150 min and max possible values in your data) to its visual coordinate, which is then used for drawing. I.e. it maps [0, 150] -> [445, 0].

To get a better understanding, I suggest reading the [official ds-scale docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale). There are also three tutorials are mentioned in the first paragraph.

Even if you found a v3 tutorial, it might be worth to read it, the ideas remain the same, just keep [the changelog page](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale) open to verify how to write the same code in v4. The biggest collection of tutorials is listed [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Tutorials).